# PySpark: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Attribute name contains invalid character(s)

Tags: csv, pyspark

I'm trying to upload a CSV-file, but I get the following error:

```
> User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
> Attribute name
> "userid,date,availability,timeslot,theme,comment,endtime,am_pm"
> contains invalid character(s) among " ,;{}()\n\t=". Please use alias
> to rename it.;
```

Could it be he sees all the columns as 1 name? And why doesn't it sees the delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly the CVS-file changes his delimiter to , instead of ; after copy-pasting the file. So by adapting the macro by saving as CSV directly into to right map, the delimiter problem is solved.